# an error when deploying a war file in tomcat 7

Tags: tomcat7

Hi all and thank you in advance for your help.

I have a war file that i'm trying to deploy using tomcat 7. This war file is named ROOT.war and is located under $TOMCAT_HOME/webapps. I also have 2 xml files (server.xml & web.xml) under $TOMCAT_HOME/conf. I get the following error when i run the following cmd: catalina.sh run

> Jul 13, 2011 2:16:23 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext filterStart
>   SEVERE: Exception starting filter LogFilter
>   java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Property 'dataSource' is required
>           at org.springframework.jdbc.support.JdbcAccessor.afterPropertiesSet(JdbcAccessor.java:134)
>           at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.(JdbcTemplate.java:141)
>           at org.springframework.jdbc.core.simple.SimpleJdbcTemplate.(SimpleJdbcTemplate.java:61)
>           at com.osi.ospoint.web.filter.LogFilter.init(LogFilter.java:92)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.initFilter(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:273)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.getFilter(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:254)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.setFilterDef(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:372)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:98)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.filterStart(StandardContext.java:4562)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext$2.call(StandardContext.java:5240)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext$2.call(StandardContext.java:5235)
>           at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
>           at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
>           at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
>   Jul 13, 2011 2:16:23 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
>   SEVERE: Error filterStart
>   Jul 13, 2011 2:16:23 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
>   SEVERE: Context [] startup failed due to previous errors

Excerpt of my server.xml

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<Server port="8000" shutdown="shutdown">
<!-- firewall friendly jconsole remote access via service:jmx:rmi://<hostname>:802/jndi/rmi://<hostname>:8015/jmxrmi using credentials defined in the jmx files -->
    <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.mbeans.JmxRemoteLifecycleListener" rmiRegistryPortPlatform="8015" rmiServerPortPlatform="8020" />
    <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.JasperListener" />
    <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.JreMemoryLeakPreventionListener" />
    <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.mbeans.GlobalResourcesLifecycleListener" />
    <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.ThreadLocalLeakPreventionListener" />
    <!-- define a datasource that is used for the web app deployed here -->
    <!-- we decided to move this into the server.xml not in context.xml for reduction of config files -->

    <Service name="some-service">
      <Executor name="some-thread-pool" namePrefix="some-thread-pool-" maxThreads="150" minSpareThreads="10" maxIdleTime="10000"/>
      <Connector address="127.0.0.1" port="8005" protocol="AJP/1.3" redirectPort="8443" executor="some-thread-pool"/>
      <Connector address="127.0.0.1" port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1"connectionTimeout="20000" redirectPort="8443" executor="some-thread-pool"/>   
      <!-- jvmRoute attribute on Engine tag not needed if apache is configured to provide this -->
      <Engine name="some-engine" defaultHost="some-host">
      <!--  <Host name="study-development-host"  appBase="webapps" unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true"/> -->
      <Host name="localhost"  appBase="webapps" unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true"/>
      <Context docBase="ROOT" path="/ROOT" />
      <WatchedResource>WEB-INF/web.xml</WatchedResource>
      <Manager pathname="" />
      <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.CometConnectionManagerValve" />
      <!-- <property name="dataSource"></property> -->
     </Engine>
    </Service>
```

The error msg above is pointing to LogFilter but the exception is raised cuz the property dataSource is not defined/present anywhere. I'm not understanding what this supposed to mean. Boys, any help on this will be greatly appreciated.

Britney

Answer (score 0):

It appears that you're using spring for the database connection. Could you add your spring configuration or bean definition?

Also, you should probably take a look at the [Spring JDBC docs](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/reference/jdbc.html). It appears that you're not specifying a datasource for Spring and it's complaining at you. Those docs explain how to give Spring a datasource.